# Proguard covert constant string value somehow

Tags: android, firebase, proguard

I'm getting issue when using proguard. For some reasons it's changing only one string value in firebase-installation library, file is com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient. I've added -keep rules but no luck.

This is how it looks in not obfuscated code
[image]

And this is after proguard obfuscation
[image]

Proguard file

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }

-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
```

I've tried a lot of proguard configs but no luck. It's changing value only for FIREBASE_INSTALLATIONS_API_VERSION field